# Cant publish a time object

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish the current wallclock time but some how during the build process it always gives an error : `Const Class ros::Time does not have any member named getMD5su`

Here is the code :

> 

```
#include "ros/xmlrpc_manager.h"  
#include  "std_msgs/Float32.h"  
#include "std_msgs/String.h"  
#include "std_msgs/Time.h"  
#include "ros/time.h"
#include "time.h"  
#include "sstream"           
using namespace std;  


int main(int argc, char **argv){

ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

ros::NodeHandle n;


ros::Publisher sum_publisher = n.advertise<std_msgs::Time>("sum", 1000);

std::cout<<ros::XMLRPCManager::instance()->getServerURI()<<std::endl;

ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
int a = 0;
int count = 0;
while (ros::ok()){

            std_msgs::Time msg;

            msg.data = ros::Time::now();

            sum_publisher.publish(msg);

            ros::spinOnce();
            loop_rate.sleep();

            //++count;

}

return 0;
```

}

I guess i should be advertising `std_msgs::Time` instead of `ros::Time` but it is not getting resolved. I already have included `ros/time.h`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289844/cant-publish-a-time-object/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you tried including `#include <std_msgs/Time.h>` ?

Also, dont mix `ros::Time` which is a class to represent Time in a ROS context and `std_msgs::Time` Which is a Time message that you can publish/subscribe.

Edit : Small example :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <std_msgs/Time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "time_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  std_msgs::Time msg;
  ros::Publisher time_publisher = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Time>("time", 1000);

  while (ros::ok()){

    msg.data = ros::Time::now();
    time_publisher .publish(msg);
  }
 }
```

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-27**:
after your comment i tried including `#include<std_msgs/Time.h` but it is not at all resolving `std_msgs::Time` So basically you mean I need to use `std_msgs::Time` to publish time messages using the class `ros::Time` ?

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2018-04-27**:
Yes and no,  I edited my answer with a small code to explain better :
You need to publish a `std_msgs/Time` message. But you need to use `ros::Time` to get the time value.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-27**:
I have edited the question and pasted my complete code, it is almost the same what you suggested, but still not getting resolved.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-27**:
Sorry, i wasnt saving my file thats why the resolution wasnt getting updated. Dumb mistake. Thanks

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-27**:
@Imathieu Could I anyhow multiply and integer or a float with time ?

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2018-04-27**:
If this works now, that great :)
you can do arithmetic time and duration : http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time
But with primitive, you can use Time::toSec() and Time::fromSec() (or toNsec and fromNsec), don't hesitate to ask a new questions

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-27**:
How can i print this time on the console ? If i use `ROS_INFO("%d",msg.data.sec)`, it always shows 0. and if i use `ROS_INFO("%d",msg.data)` it gives me some garbage value. I guess that is because `%d` is for integers. Also, shouldnt it give the actual wall clock time ?

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-27**:
for the second part of my question : multipying with time, i meant [q289766](https://answers.ros.org/question/289766/how-to-write-a-function-in-ros2/)